# Circular dependency for image "Normal" from object "Plane" while baking

Tags: baking, error, normal-map, displacement

I tried to create normal map from a 2D texture image (.jpg-file size:1024px*1024px) like it is explained in this video:

https://youtu.be/Hpdwo6F_WYQ

I am using Blender 2.82 and everytime I try to bake a normal map I get this error:

[image: Exception]

I am trying to get a simple 2D texture normal map to make like a sandy beach.

**EDIT:**

The material tab looks like

[image: The material]

Comment: I think you are baking to the "Image Texture" node that is linked to your material. Could you post your node tree setup ?

Comment: I am new to blender, can you explain to me where I can find that?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello :). Just a guess - the tutorial guy changes *Influence > Space* to *Object*, while yours is still set to *Tangent*.

Comment: @JachymMichal that fixed it. Lol I missed that, but the circular dependency message still occurs

Comment: @Gorgious I'm doing a loop on 2 objects that have the same materials in them. And I dynamically add an Image Texture to the object's materials and set it with a new black image and then bake the diffuse color with `bpy.ops.object.bake(type='DIFFUSE')` then remove the image texture and for the next object in the loop, add new image texture with new image again on those materials and do the same thing. causing a cyclical error. Every instance is new, nothing is linked. Unfortunately I don't understand what fixed this problem in this thread.

Answer (score 3):

The circular dependency error means you are trying to bake to the same image where you need a separate image meant as a baking target, or that you have 'bake from selected to active' checked and are only needing to bake a single object. Untick that option and you should be able to bake to a new image texture that is selected in your node tree.